# How to change displayed html content in view using jquery - codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I'm not so sure about how to type this question title, but anyway

I have code like this in my view called content.php

```
<div class="fix single_content floatleft">
    <h2><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/New.png')?>" alt="" width="24" height="24"></img><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/Main_Controller/loadKeluhan')?>" >New</a> </h2>
    <?php include 'tableLoad.php' ?>      
    <p class="viewall"><a href="#">view more </a> &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-hand-o-right"></i></p>
  </div>
```

And in its looks like this in tableLoad.php

```
<div class="fix"><ul id="newTable"><?php  
      $i=0;
      while($i<count($array)){
          echo '<li>
          <div class="entry_name floatleft"><a href="pages/single.html"><img src="assets/images/mozilla.png" alt="">'.$array[$i].'</a></div>
          <div class="download-count floatright"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> 4578</div>
          </li>';
          $i++;
      }
          ?></ul></div>
```

`$array[i]` is a forwarded variable from my controller which have list of item I need from my database.

I want to have it refreshed every 2 second so it will change the display if something changed from the database. I use my code in jQuery like this to do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){setInterval(function(){
$('#newTable').html("<?php include 'tableLoad.php'; ?>")
}, 2000);});
```

The problem is that every time jQuery code run, it show nothing and there is no error report in browser's console. The codes in php run well, but the one from jQuery did not.

Can anybody please give me some enlightment?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English

### SOLVED

Solution :

I change my js code to Ajax and call function from controller with it like poonam said. The js file become like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval('autoRefresh_div()', 2000);
}); 
function autoRefresh_div()
 {
   $.ajax({
        dataType:'text',
        type: "POST",
        url: BASE_URL+'index.php/Main_Controller/loadKeluhan',
        success: function (response){

           $("#newTable").html(response);

          }
    });}
```

with loadKeluhan is a function in my Main_Controller to load tableLoad view and pass new array value to it.

Comment: you need to load view in controller and then use this url in ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `load()`

Try this:

```
 function autoRefresh_div()
 {
      $("#newTable").load("tableLoad.php");// a function which will load data from other file after x seconds
  }

  setInterval('autoRefresh_div()', 2000); // refresh div after 2 secs
```

And use this:

```
    <div class="fix single_content floatleft">
            <h2><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/New.png')?>" alt="" width="24" height="24"></img><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/Main_Controller/loadKeluhan')?>" >New</a> </h2>
         <div class="fix"><ul id="newTable">
            <?php include 'tableLoad.php' ?>   
         </ul>         
         </div>   
            <p class="viewall"><a href="#">view more </a> &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-hand-o-right"></i></p>
          </div>
```

Get only `<li>` from `tableLoad.php`.

Similarly you can use `$.ajax()` or `$.post()` etc instead of `load()` function and put the response in `div` or `ul`.

**With `$.ajax()`**

```
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
 function autoRefresh_div()
 {

    $.ajax({
            dataType:'text',
            type: "POST",
            url: 'url_to_your_file or function',
            success: function (response){

               $("#newTable").html(response);

              }
        });
  }

  setInterval('autoRefresh_div()', 2000); // refresh div after 2 secs
            </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have tried this solution before, but it give me 404 error because the file is not on same directory. When I try to load it using path to tableLoad.php, it gives me 403 error forbidden. This maybe because of codeigniter structure, but don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Then you should use `$.ajax()`. It's much better and efficient

Comment: I don't quite understand how to use ajax yet. Could you give me some example how to solve this with ajax?

Comment: I used this as url path to file. url: BASE_URL+'application/view/loadTable.php'. But still got 403 forbidden error

Comment: `BASE_URL` is a php variable so use it in php tag `url: '<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>application/view/loadTable.php'`

Comment: BASE_URL is an already defined variable from javascript which contain "<?php echo base_url();?>". So this should not be the problem. Sorry for not mentioning it before

Comment: you had given `../view/loadTable.php` in `url`.. It's not true i think.. `url` should be of the function in controller